# In Game of Thrones, is it possible for Danaerys's child to still be alive?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Was Daenerys' baby pronounced dead or was the body seen when it was dead? Also how does anyone that the body was Daenerys' baby? Couldn't the mid-wife have taken Daenerys' baby for her own or sold it and pretended that it died? If answered please give evidence, I already read the wikia, it didn't have a satisfactory answer.

Is there any canon evidence that either suggests that this is possible, or shows that this cannot be the case?

Comment: I think Jorah was present, and with his fanatical devotion to Danaerys I don't think he would have allowed this.

Comment: Jorah carried her to the tent, but was not there for the birth. He says "the women say" when asked about the child. Mirri Maaz Duur delivered it.

Comment: And does that not seem suspect. What happened to the baby, there are currently only 2 Tangaryns, but there are 3 if we tally the baby, we must know if the baby is alive. Someone had to tally the baby.

Comment: Everything we know about Rhaego's death (or not) is contained in that chapter, and there's little of it as it is. So any further speculation on that matter would be in the tin foil hat category. Not that there's anything wrong with that :)

Comment: Dany herself says that she knew Rhaego was dead before she woke up. She saw him consumed by fire in her fever dreams. Also, Mirri Maaz Duur remained with the khalasar, she would not be able to hide the baby. What's more, the newly made khals would have made sure the baby was dead.

Comment: I assume you refer to Dany and Aegon, though it is highly likely that Aegon is the mummer's dragon (the false dragon) from the prophecy of the Undying of Qarth, and also from [Quaithe's](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Quaithe) statement in ADWD: `Kraken and dark flame, lion and griffin, the sun's son and the mummer's dragon.`

Comment: Danaerys could have been given something to halucinate the baby was dead. Also a liar was in charge of the baby, the baby could have been alive. And don't say "They would have made sure the baby was dead", oh really, like they made sure Arya and probably others were dead. That making sure people are dead system is riddled with error, if you haven't noticed. The baby could be alive and that is probably a secret plot point, all we need is evidence from someone who watched the sereies, read the book and talked to Martin. I only read the book.

Comment: Of course it's possible -- how could it be otherwise? All it takes is for George R R Martin to write the words "Suddenly Dany saw her two-year-old child, who had mysteriously survived" in _The Winds of Winter_, and he'll turn out to be alive. So this is really a question about the contents of Mr Martin's mind and is therefore unanswerable.

Comment: Any plans Mirri Maaz Duur would have had to do something like this were foiled when they tied her to Khal Drogo's funeral pyre. So, barring something like @MikeScott s suggestion, the child is dead.

Comment: “how does anyone that the body was Daenerys' baby” — it... came out of her vajayjay?

Comment: The child was the blood sacrifice price that Daenerys implicitly agreed to pay to save Drogo's life.

Answer (score 14):

It's not really feasible that Mirri Maaz Duur took the child without anyone knowing. Although she delivered the baby, she wasn't alone in the tent; Danaerys' hand-maidens were also in there.

> “He never lived, my princess. The women say He faltered, and Dany saw
>   how the flesh hung  loose on him, and the way he limped when he moved.
>
> “Tell me. Tell me what the women say.”
>
> He turned his face away. His eyes were haunted. “They say the child
>   was...”
>
> She waited, but Ser Jorah could not say it. His face grew dark with
>   shame. He looked half a  corpse himself.
>
> “Monstrous,” Mirri Maz Duur finished for him. The knight was a
>   powerful man, yet Dany  understood in that moment that the maegi was
>   stronger, and crueler, and infinitely more  dangerous. “Twisted. I
>   drew him forth myself. He was scaled like a lizard, blind, with the
>   stub of a tail and small leather wings like the wings of a bat. When I
>   touched him, the flesh sloughed off the bone, and inside he was full
>   of graveworms and the stink of corruption. He had been dead for
>   years.”

He says "the women say", not "Mirri says" implying that there were a few women in the tent.

Comment: How can a baby just being born be "dead for years"?

Comment: @Mkalafut magic

Comment: The reason why I didn't accept your answer was that it does not answer all the possibilities. I have to 1+ for your thoughtfulness,but I think that assuming the baby is dead without real proof is not a safe assumption. Because while I agree a little with your answer I don't think it theorizes enough with canon material. I don't think we can safely assume that the baby is dead. But I think you answered 1 part of the question.